# How to edit C# code in a .net DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, decompiler

I have used many decompilers but have too little experience to understand where it is that I can edit the c# code of specific objects within the DLL. Is it possible to simply edit the C# code and save the changes? If so how could I go about doing this?

TL:DR
How do I edit C# code inside a DLL that I do not have the source code for?

Comment: This is not something that can easily be done.

Comment: What about code injections or completely decompiling the DLL the way you can decompile and edit an apk

Comment: There is no C# code in a DLL. An assembly contains Immediate Language, which can sometimes be decompiled to C#. Then you can edit the code and compile an assembly from that code again. Plenty of questions about this subject, try searching.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, but it is though. ILSpy and other tools can do it.

Comment: @lonewolf ILSpy and others ***decompile*** code. But if even the cheapest code obfuscator has been run on the code it will not re-compile after decompiling due to non valid method names for C#.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can edit & patch .NET DLL/EXE with https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

Worked perfectly well for me.